# How to go to specific commit in git

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have commited in git and i want to go to the second commit.I have used

```
git checkout <commit id>
```

```
commit 3f54a651504adc885a71db275e0fb4a5a1111cf4 (HEAD -> dev_coder, origin/dev_coder)
Author: Coder <coder@me.com>
Date:   Sun Jun 27 20:23:48 2021 +0530

   button 

commit 362d11072139bda8569dcf37012174258e8078c3
Author: Coder <coder@me.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 25 14:30:01 2021 +0530

    updated owner

commit 0db31695b550748c27486248974ee6f57c88458
Author: Coder <coder@me.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 16 21:25:28 2021 +0530

    Added  field

commit 2c72f1ef0bd6a6e7da785212a05efa08a308f1fa
Author: Coder <coder@me.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 11 10:36:01 2021 +0530
```

I am in a branch call dev_coder and not in the main branch.I want to go to the 362d11072139bda8569dcf37012174258e8078c3 commit.When i used the bellow one it chages the branch and show somethign else.

```
git chekout 362d11072139bda8569dcf37012174258e8078c3
```

Comment: It will create a "detached HEAD". if you want to make commits at this point, you will need to create a new branch. Or are you trying to rollback the last commit?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You need to explain bit more your intentions are if someone is to help you. For example : what situation would you like to reach ? what's not ok at the moment ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question title is : "How to go to specific commit in git", and actually, you have already achieved that : `git checkout 362d110` will set your repository to the state in that commit.

Typing a straight commit hash as a target, however, also sets your repo to a so called "detached HEAD" state, which may be disturbing if you are new to git.

If your intention is to *work on a new branch* starting from there, you can create a branch, and instruct git to use it as the active branch :

```
git branch my-work
git checkout my-work
# you will now be working on a branch named 'my-work'
```

There is actually a shortcut to do this in one single command :

```
git checkout -b my-work
```